# Add buttons to google sheets that links me to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im in need for a script that when I make a button in google sheets. I can click on it and will take me to another work sheet. Something like below but I cant get this to work

```
function GoToSheet1() {
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'INSERT_SPREADSHEET_URL_HERE';
  // Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet.
  var SHEET_NAME = 'INSERT_SHEET_NAME_HERE';
```

Thanks in advance Jarrad

Answer (score 4):

This is as simple as this:

```
function SwitchToSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('NAME OF THE SHEET'), true);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you just insert a hyperlink into a cell and format it (colours, borders etc) so it "looks" like a button?  Then protect that cell so other users can't alter it.  A formula you could enter into a cell would be simply:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://link.to.spreadsheet", "Button Text")
```

If you need something more complex, and hence a script, we'll need more information.  I'm not sure why you'd use a script for the purpose you have explained.

For example - is the sheet (link) different for each row of the spreadsheet, or different for each worksheet within the spreadsheet.  Perhaps share a redacted screenshot of the spreadsheet to give us more of an idea of what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way.

In script file, enter this function:

```
function SwitchToIntro() {
  //go to sheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME').activate();

  //go to Range in this sheet(tab/section)
  target.getRange("yourRange") /**or**/ target.getRangeByName("NAMED_RANGE") /**followed by**/ .activate();
};
```

Then in the spreadsheet go to: INSERT > DRAWING.

Draw your button, there's shapes in the top bar.

Then right-click the drawing you just inserted and in the option you have "Assign a script".

This is imho the shortest way to make buttons and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with a sidebar or a dialog.  I like sidebars better but hey take up more room.  You modify this so that you only get the sheets you want.

```
  function showGoToSheet() {

  var allsheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
  var s = '<style>#mySheets{margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;background-color:#cccccc;}#btn0, #btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4, #btn5, #btn6, #btn7, #btn8{margin:0px 5px 5px 0px;}</style><div id="mySheets">';
  for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) 
  {
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    if (sheet_name != 'ActivityLog' && sheet_name != 'AllData' && sheet_name != 'Scratch' && sheet_name != 'Data Validation')
    {
      s += '<input id="btn' + i +'" type="button" value="Go to: ' + sheet_name + '" onClick="google.script.run.getMySheet(\'' + sheet_name + '\');" /><br />';
    }
  }
  s += '<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /></div>';
  //myUtilities.dispStatus('My Sheets',s,600,400);
  var html=HtmlService().createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(600).setHeight(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'My Sheets');
}
```

Or you can try to use the little icon in the lower left of your spreadsheet.  I like the little icon if you have a lot of sheets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Ideas but I still would like to go with the buttons over the sheet. I want to make a dashboard so if I click on 1 button it takes me to a particular sheet on a particular tab. like below but with links

function ph() {
// 1 = row 1, 14 = column 14 = N
goToSheet("Data Interpretation", 47, 1);
}

function goToSheet(sheetName, row, col) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
var range = sheet.getRange(row, col)
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}

Answer (score 0):

This works, simply alter Home to the name of the sheet you need:

```
function showSheetByName(Name) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Name);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}

function Home() {
    showSheetByName("Home");
}
```